# Nesting html documents inline

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm wanting to set up something to where I can write an html document within another html document, and then render the nested html document inline. I know the common argument is this is not something that would be to be done, but I have two reasons for wanting to do it:

1. I want to cut down on the number of physical files I am managing, so iframes or rendering partials is not exactly what I am after, as they require an actual separate document to render.
2. I want to be able to show an example of some html, then load an html document showing what that would look like in a browser right there on the same page without using images.

I know this is possible, as several online html editors allow you to write html, then generate the html off to the side, and I suppose this could just be partials that dynamically re-write the file that in the partial, but surely not all of them are doing this, so is there a way besides using iframes or partials to accomplish this? I'm using asp.net mvc with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Online Editors render the HTML by injecting your HTML code in the editor as a child elements inside another container that's supposed to act as the preview container.

There is no server-side activity other than just storing the HTML snippets(partials stored in the DB in case they are preloaded).

It could be done as a pure client-side activity. Of course, you'll have to write a custom renderer  that will parse the contents of the user passed code,
strip out the HTML tag, load the scripts and other references on the head tag,set the title as given in the head tag and append the contents of the body tag into the presentation div.

But then this is a hassle.
Better to store the HTML in the DB/app cache and render it via an iframe, that way you don't have to deal with loads of partials. Just CRUD.
/=======================================================================
UPDATE: Response to clarification

Yes, it is possible. Embed your "inner-html" as a 'javascript template string variable' within your "main-html" document. 
Some thing like this :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  // <![CDATA[
           var innerhtml1 = `
                            <div> 
                              <p>This markup is part of innerhtml1</p>
                            </div>
                           `;
           // ]]>
    </script>
```

(I'm not sure if you'll really need the CDATA section if you want to use the template literal thing, though.)

Then you could just perform

`$("#container1").html(innerhtml1);`

on the "main-html" document and **make sure you just don't have HTML and body tags. But just enough markup for what you want to show(like above).**

If you really have HTML and body tags.You should find a way to just scoop out the contents of the body tag of the source string and insert it into the preview container.This should be easy to pass the string through a regex and scoop stuff between the  and  tags.
But I'm pretty sure you might not need this.

This way you can virtually store tonnes (kidding) of HTML docs within your one html page.

Codepen Link here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOJMwo?editors=1010#0

Beware this only works on browsers that support the template literal thing.(Its pretty good as of now. See here : [EcmaScript6 template strings support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#template_strings))
Otherwise you can still use the standard string but you'll have to use escaping and other processing to properly format it.before being able to directly inject it.

Comment: I should clarify then, I want to have this be html in an html doc that I wrote, for example I have a code snippet that I want to show the result of later in the page, without needing to render a separate page, that way my file count stays low, is this possible?

Comment: I have updated the answer with whatever i think i understand you need.